# Javascript Alert box not displaying

Tags: javascript, arrays, alert

Ok so I still pretty new to programming but I can not wrap my head around why this code on jsbin doesn't work. I would think an alert box should pop up with with first value of the array which is the string "red" but nothing happens. I don't understand what the warnings are telling me either. I am sure its something simple but I just can't get it.

Live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/XZbnr/

Code:

```
var colors = [“red”, “blue”, “green”]; 
alert(colors[0]);
```

Comment: *'Alert box not di'*..?

Comment: Probably "displaying"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have some special characters in there:

```
var colors = [“red”, “blue”, “green”];
```

Those quotes appear to be pasted from Microsoft Word, or similar.

Replace them with " and it will work:

```
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]; 
alert(colors[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XZbnr/1/

Comment: oh ok, thank you. I did pull them from a ebook that I have been learning from and didn't realize that could be a problem. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! The author of the ebook probably used Microsoft Word (or similar) somewhere in the writing process. Word automatically converts standard " to those smart quotes. This is something to watch out for no matter what programming languages you use.

Comment: Which, incidentally, is why most code books tell you to use either a dedicated IDE, or a basic text-editor (such as Text Mate, Notepad, Notepad++, gedit or so forth).

Answer (score 2):

Replace “ with normal quotes: " or '

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the wrong kind of quotation marks. Try just using " or '